# Pass a Value when delete button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, commandfield

I have a delete button on a `gridview` for each row that calls `gvSiteInfo_RowDeleting(object sender, EventArgs e)` when it is clicked.    How do I find out the value of the row number of the clicked delete button?   I need to have the row number in the delete method where i specify with `<< NEED ROW NUMBER HERE!! >>`

So far I haven't been able to turn up anything searching the web and when i print out the values of `sender` and `e` they don't tell me anything useful.

```
 protected void gvSiteInfo_RowDeleting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SiteDB site = new SiteDB();
        site.SelectedConnectionString = "SQLDEV08";
        site.deleteSite(<<<NEED ROW NUMBER HERE!!>>>);
    }

<asp:GridView ID="gvSiteInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="gvSiteInfo_Sorting" width="100%"
    AllowSorting="True" OnRowDeleting="gvSiteInfo_RowDeleting" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowCancelButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodServer" HeaderText="Production Server" 
            SortExpression="prodServer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodIP" HeaderText="Production IP Address" 
            SortExpression="prodIP" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" 
            SortExpression="Priority" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Platform" HeaderText="Platform" 
            SortExpression="Platform" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RowDeleting event actually takes [GridViewDeleteEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.aspx), not your standard EventArgs. There is a `RowIndex` property on the former that will give you the index of the row being deleted.

Comment: when i tried passing `GridViewDeleteEventArgs` I would get this error
"CS0123: No overload for 'gvSiteInfo_RowDeleting' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventHandler'"   when i tried to run my page so I had to change it to EventArgs

Comment: You probably used `GridViewDeletedEventArgs` instead of `GridViewDeleteEventArgs`. The past-or-present tense of "Deleted" makes a difference.. it's a separate event that occurs after deletion.

Comment: Hmm, that could be.  I will try it the way that you suggest and let you know if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: That worked, I can load that page and get into the `gvSiteInfo_RowDeleting` method now.    Thanks for your help!